# How to assign CTE result into store procedure output parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

Here i try to return CTE result in store procedure OUTPUR parameter, I try these on my own so i dont know whether i doing correct in the matter of assigning output parameter in CTE .Now this store procedure didnt executing....please help ? Thanks in advance !!!

```
-----Store Procedure----------
    create procedure proc_return_2val 
         @name nvarchar(60)=null,
         @name_count int output, 
         @row_count int output
    as
    begin
        select @name_count=COUNT(*) from customer_detail where customer_name like '%' + @name + '%'
        with cte as
        (
            select temp=ROW_NUMBER() over(order by(select 0)) from customer_detail
        )
        select @row_count=temp from cte;
    end

----command to display results-------
declare @a as int,@b as int
exec proc_return_2val 'am', @a output, @b output
select @a output, @b output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output in your stored procedure works just fine, your issue is the bad select inside the procedure. You are currently assigning several values to @row_count leaving only the last random value. This is a rewrite of your procedure to what I imagine you are trying:

```
create procedure proc_return_2val 
  @name       nvarchar(60)=null, 
  @name_count int output, 
  @row_count  int output
as
begin
    select @name_count=COUNT(*) from customer_detail where customer_name like '%' + @name + '%'
    select @row_count =COUNT(*) from customer_detail
end
```

Since you insist on using CTE for row_count. This is how you could do it (not how i would do it):

```
;with cte as
(
    select temp=count(*) from customer_detail
)
select @row_count=temp from cte;
```

Comment: ----  I agree with ur way of solution....but i try to get those row_count result by using CTE within store procedure. since iam a learner i trying out the possible ways for same result...now i looking about the bug in my above question ...please mention if u find......or share your's view for better way to solve with CTE in store procedure according to above mentioned criteria....thanks in advance

Comment: your can't put more than 1 value into an integer variable. If you need all the numbers from 1 to rowcount, you do not use the output parameter. Select them into a DataTableReader (in .net)

Comment: No, you wrongly understood my last comment.....your above solution is right and that result only i too try to get with CTE.... i mean i try to display row_count only not row contents...ur previous answer is correct on that way...... but i try to know how to get that row_count using CTE and how to assign that row_count(variable temp which is created within cte) in output parameter correctly....

Comment: Thanks, i found the mistake what i did, i miss semicolon after my first select statement.after i put it working.

Comment: ok now i get it, it is not because you need semicolon after select, but when you have other script, you normally need semicolon before ;WITH